# Connecting Computers over Networks

Tags: java, sockets, networking

**Question**

Is there a networking system that anyone can suggest? One that meets the requirements of: not needing a server, connecting between different computers on different networks.

**Background**

Before you start: yes. I do have plenty experience with Java (created games etc...)- I just don't know anything at all about networking. I need to somehow make a simple multiplayer game with Java. I cannot use a server, because I'm just a 9th grader with no money to buy one. I have done some research and I heard of this thing called peer to peer networking, and socket stuff. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out. Many of the videos and research I've done on non-server networking seems to say the same thing: use servers, however if you continue with this unsafe, insecure route, here is how to connect two computers on the same network. It's driving me insane.

**Extra Information**

The game is nothing complicated. It's just a simple card game that my friend made, and we are trying to turn it into a videogame. All it needs to do really is just send strings back and forth between two different computers on different networks. Nothing complicated.

**Requirements**

- Networking system that can connect two computers
- Connection between computers on different networks
- Does not require the use of a physical server

If anyone has any suggestions to a system that complies with the requirements, I would greatly appreciate it! Thank you in advance.

Comment: You forgot to ask a (concrete) question.

Comment: All of this could be started with your server and client on a single machine. Just google "java network programming"

Comment: (A) There is nothing special about a “server”. You can make network connections between any two computers you choose. A server is simply a computer dedicated to network connections versus a human user. (B) Your post here is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Read the Help page. This site is for narrowly-focused questions on a specific programming problem/need. For general guidance use a forums site such a JavaRanch.com.

Comment: You don't need to buy a server. A server is just a differently shaped computer. It's just a computer. You can run the server *program* on your *normal* computer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I heard of this thing called peer to peer networking

Sure there is a peer to peer networking and you can find practical application of this technology e.g. in online communication. It's more related to JS and web dev.

Anyway, as soon as you start dig deeper in this topic you will find out that peer to peer connection is difficult to establish and maintain and, because of that, it's not commonly used. All communication apps like MSTeams, Zoom etc. rely on servers.

So, it definitely won't work out properly. You can manage to connect 2 player somehow but as soon as amount of players start growing up it will be impossible to keep the connection.

> One that meets the requirements of: not needing a server, connecting between different computers on different networks

What about this: read smth about switches and routers and LANs. What is the purpose of these devices. Shortly: you can easily provide a communication among computers in the same LAN and even among different LANs [google smth like that](https://www.practicalnetworking.net/stand-alone/communication-through-multiple-switches/)

Comment: The reason it is difficult to establish, is because of NAT routers hiding a whole network behind a single ip-number, which typically all clients are behind.